# Making certain products of three nonsingular matrices positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $A,C$ be two nonsingular (real or complex) square matrices. I do *not* assume that $A$ and $C$ commute.

> **Question - Part 1:** is there a third square matrix $B$ such that:
>
> - $B$ is also nonsingular;
> - $B$ commutes with both $A$ and $C$;
> - $ABC$ is positive definite?

More generally, consider nonsingular (real or complex), *not necessarily commuting* square matrices $A,C_1,\ldots,C_k$.

> **Question - Part 2:** are there square matrices $B_1,\ldots,B_k$ such that:
>
> - $B_j$ is nonsingular for all $j=1,\ldots,k$;
> - $B_j$ commutes with $A$ and $C_i$ for all $i,j=1,\ldots,k$;
> - $AB_jC_j$ is positive definite for all $j=1,\ldots,k$?

Therefore, Part 1 is the case $k=1$ of Part 2. I am particularly interested in the situation when $A$ and $AC_j$ are Hermitian for all $j=1,\ldots,k$.

> **Question - Part 3:** Let $A,B_1,\ldots,B_k,C_1,\ldots,C_k$ be as in Part 2 with $A,C_1,\ldots,C_k$ as in the previous paragraph. Can one choose the $B_j$'s in such a way that $AB_j$ are also Hermitian for all $j=1,\ldots,k$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers to your first two questions are "no" in general. E.g. consider
$$
A=\pmatrix{1\\ &-1},\ C=\pmatrix{1&1\\ -1&1}.
$$
Any matrix $B$ that commutes with $A$ must be diagonal. However, if $B$ has two different diagonal entries, then $B$ and $C$ do not commute; if $B$ is a nonzero multiple of $I$ instead, then $ABC$ is not positive definite because the product has zero trace.

Comment: Thanks. However, in your example $AC$ is not Hermitian since $A$ and $C$ do not commute. What if we are in the situation described in Part 3 - i.e. $A$ and $AC$ are required to be Hermitian? In such a case, if $A$ and $C$ do not commute, then $C$ cannot be Hermitian.

Comment: @PedroLauridsenRibeiro See my new edit.

Comment: That is a good example, thanks! It also easily extends to the higher-rank case by taking block-diagonal matrices.